# "Error // Usage: rails new APP_PATH [options] //" when create a new static web pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am newbie with Rails and trying to make a new static web pages by this command in cmd

`rails generate controller pages about location`

before ran this command, I am sure that I set up rails ok. But I got those error

[image]

Here is some more information about my rails, when I ran

`rails -v : Rails 6.0.3.2`

I am very confusing because of this problem, could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you are sure you are inside the rails project dorectory?

Comment: Hey @anhbuiask can you try this: `rails generate controller Pages about location`